# TensorFlow: "UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have a multi-input network I am trying to create. Each Input has it's respective dtype. I have 4 String Tensors and 2 Float Tensors. The Output is a String Tensor also. I can't seem to find what exactly is causing the error. The error also occurs when I attempt to train my model.

```
Training model....
Epoch 1/200
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-38584befa568> in <module>
      1 # Train Model
      2 print('Training model....')
----> 3 model.fit(x=[Date_Train_Input, Team_One_Train_Input, Team_Two_Train_Input, Team_One_Stats_Train_Input, Team_Two_Stats_Train_Input],
      4          y=Train_Output,
      5           validation_data=([Date_Input_Validate, Team_One_Input_Validate, Team_Two_Input_Validate, Team_One_Stats_Input_Validate, Team_Two_Stats_Input_Validate], Output_Validate),

~/Documents/Python Projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

~/Documents/Python Projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~/Documents/Python Projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    853       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    854       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 855       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    856     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    857       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

~/Documents/Python Projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2940       (graph_function,
   2941        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2942     return graph_function._call_flat(
   2943         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2944 

~/Documents/Python Projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1916         and executing_eagerly):
   1917       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1918       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1919           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1920     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

~/Documents/Python Projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    553       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    554         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 555           outputs = execute.execute(
    556               str(self.signature.name),
    557               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

~/Documents/Python Projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
     [[node model_30/Cast (defined at <ipython-input-124-38584befa568>:3) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5842]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I've attached the Code Below as requested.

```
# Import Necessary Modules
import tensorflow as tf
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np

# Import Dataset
workbook = load_workbook('/Users/BOBJOE/Documents/Python Projects/Tensor Flow/ML NBA Predictor/Traning_Data_Redo1.xlsx', read_only=True)

Input_book = workbook['Input Data']

Output_book = workbook['Output Data']

tf_Input = {'Date': [], 'Team One': [], 'Team Two': [], 'Team One Stats': [], 'Team Two Stats': []}

# Organize Input Data
for col in Input_book:
    Date = []
    Team_One = []
    Team_Two = []
    Team_One_Stats = []
    Team_Two_Stats = []
    First_Team = True
    
    for cell in col:
        if cell.value is None:
            pass
        elif isinstance(cell.value, str) and 'T00' in cell.value:
            Date.append(cell.value)
        elif isinstance(cell.value, str) and len(cell.value) == 3 and 0 == len(Team_One):
            Team_One.append(cell.value)
        elif isinstance(cell.value, str) and len(cell.value) == 3 and 3 == len(Team_One[0]):
            First_Team = False
        elif First_Team and isinstance(cell.value, str):
            Team_One.append(cell.value)
        elif First_Team and isinstance(cell.value, float):
            Team_One_Stats.append(cell.value)
        elif isinstance(cell.value, str):
            Team_Two.append(cell.value)
        elif isinstance(cell.value, float):
            Team_Two_Stats.append(cell.value)
    
    tf_Input['Date'].append(Date)
    tf_Input['Team One'].append(Team_One)
    tf_Input['Team Two'].append(Team_Two)
    tf_Input['Team One Stats'].append(Team_One_Stats)
    tf_Input['Team Two Stats'].append(Team_Two_Stats)
        
            
            

# Make all List Even Sizes
for i in tf_Input['Team One']:
    while len(i) < 11:
        i.append('No Name')

for i in tf_Input['Team Two']:
    while len(i) < 11:
        i.append('No Name')

for i in tf_Input['Team One Stats']:
    while len(i) < 250:
        i.append(0)
        
for i in tf_Input['Team Two Stats']:
    while len(i) < 250:
        i.append(0)
        
for i in tf_Input['Date']:
    while len(i) < 1:
        i.append('No Date')

# Get Rid of all Nones in List
for i in tf_Input['Team One']:
    i = ['No Name' if v is None else v for v in i]

for i in tf_Input['Team Two']:
    i = ['No Name' if v is None else v for v in i]

for i in tf_Input['Team One Stats']:
    i = [0 if v is None else v for v in i]
        
for i in tf_Input['Team Two Stats']:
    i = [0 if v is None else v for v in i]
        
for i in tf_Input['Date']:
    i = ['No Date' if v is None else v for v in i]

# Clean Output Data
Output_Data_Set = []

for col in Output_book:
    Output_List = []
    
    for cell in col:
        Output_List.append(str(cell.value))
    
    if len(Output_List) < 4:
        Output_List.extend('0')
        
    Output_List = ['0' if v is None else v for v in Output_List]

    Output_Data_Set.append(Output_List)

# Split Training Data
Date_Train_Input, Date_Input_Validate, Date_Input_Test  = np.split(tf_Input['Date'], [int(len(tf_Input['Date'])*0.6), int(len(tf_Input['Date'])*0.8)])
Team_One_Train_Input, Team_One_Input_Validate, Team_One_Input_Test  = np.split(tf_Input['Team One'], [int(len(tf_Input['Team One'])*0.6), int(len(tf_Input['Team One'])*0.8)])
Team_Two_Train_Input, Team_Two_Input_Validate, Team_Two_Input_Test  = np.split(tf_Input['Team Two'], [int(len(tf_Input['Team Two'])*0.6), int(len(tf_Input['Team Two'])*0.8)])
Team_One_Stats_Train_Input, Team_One_Stats_Input_Validate, Team_One_Stats_Input_Test  = np.split(tf_Input['Team One Stats'], [int(len(tf_Input['Team One Stats'])*0.6), int(len(tf_Input['Team One Stats'])*0.8)])
Team_Two_Stats_Train_Input, Team_Two_Stats_Input_Validate, Team_Two_Stats_Input_Test  = np.split(tf_Input['Team Two Stats'], [int(len(tf_Input['Team Two Stats'])*0.6), int(len(tf_Input['Team Two Stats'])*0.8)])

# Split Output Data
Train_Output, Output_Validate, Output_Test  = np.split(Output_Data_Set, [int(len(Output_Data_Set)*0.6), int(len(Output_Data_Set)*0.8)])

Train_Output = Train_Output.astype('str')
Date_Train_Input = Date_Train_Input.astype('str')
Team_One_Train_Input = Team_One_Train_Input.astype('str')
Team_Two_Train_Input = Team_Two_Train_Input.astype('str')
Team_One_Stats_Train_Input = Team_One_Stats_Train_Input.astype('float64')
Team_Two_Stats_Train_Input = Team_Two_Stats_Train_Input.astype('float64')

Output_Validate = Output_Validate.astype('str')
Date_Input_Validate = Date_Input_Validate.astype('str')
Team_One_Input_Validate = Team_One_Input_Validate.astype('str')
Team_Two_Input_Validate = Team_Two_Input_Validate.astype('str')
Team_One_Stats_Input_Validate = Team_One_Stats_Input_Validate.astype('float64')
Team_Two_Stats_Input_Validate = Team_Two_Stats_Input_Validate.astype('float64')

# Define Inputs
Date_Input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
Team_One_Input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(11,))
Team_Two_Input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(11,))
Team_One_Stats_Input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(250,))
Team_Two_Stats_Input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(250,))


# Define Branches for Each Input (Date)
Date = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(Date_Input)
Date = tf.keras.Model(inputs=Date_Input, outputs=Date)

# Team One
Team_One = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(Team_One_Input)
Team_One = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(Team_One)
Team_One = tf.keras.Model(inputs=Team_One_Input, outputs=Team_One)

# Team Two
Team_Two = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(Team_Two_Input)
Team_Two = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(Team_Two)
Team_Two = tf.keras.Model(inputs=Team_Two_Input, outputs=Team_Two)

# Team One Stats
Team_One_Stats = tf.keras.layers.Dense(125, activation='relu')(Team_One_Stats_Input)
Team_One_Stats = tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation='relu')(Team_One_Stats)
Team_One_Stats = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu')(Team_One_Stats)
Team_One_Stats = tf.keras.Model(inputs=Team_One_Stats_Input, outputs=Team_One_Stats)

# Team Two Stats
Team_Two_Stats = tf.keras.layers.Dense(125, activation='relu')(Team_Two_Stats_Input)
Team_Two_Stats = tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation='relu')(Team_Two_Stats)
Team_Two_Stats = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu')(Team_Two_Stats)
Team_Two_Stats = tf.keras.Model(inputs=Team_Two_Stats_Input, outputs=Team_Two_Stats)

# Combine the outputs of all branches
combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([Date.output, Team_One.output, Team_Two.output, Team_One_Stats.output, Team_Two_Stats.output])

# FC Layer
z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='relu')(combined)
z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='linear')(z)

# Setup Model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[Date.input, Team_One.input, Team_Two.input, Team_One_Stats.input, Team_Two_Stats.input], outputs=z)

# Optimize
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200)
model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_percentage_error", optimizer=opt)

# Convert to Tensor Train Data
Date_Train_Input = tf.convert_to_tensor(Date_Train_Input)
Team_One_Train_Input = tf.convert_to_tensor(Team_One_Train_Input)
Team_Two_Train_Input = tf.convert_to_tensor(Team_Two_Train_Input)
Team_One_Stats_Train_Input = tf.convert_to_tensor(Team_One_Stats_Train_Input)
Team_Two_Stats_Train_Input = tf.convert_to_tensor(Team_Two_Stats_Train_Input)
Train_Output = tf.convert_to_tensor(Train_Output)

# Convert to Tensor Validate
Date_Input_Validate = tf.convert_to_tensor(Date_Input_Validate)
Team_One_Input_Validate = tf.convert_to_tensor(Team_One_Input_Validate)
Team_Two_Input_Validate = tf.convert_to_tensor(Team_Two_Input_Validate)
Team_One_Stats_Input_Validate = tf.convert_to_tensor(Team_One_Stats_Input_Validate)
Team_Two_Stats_Input_Validate = tf.convert_to_tensor(Team_Two_Stats_Input_Validate)
Output_Validate = tf.convert_to_tensor(Output_Validate)

# Train Model
print('Training model....')
model.fit(x=[Date_Train_Input, Team_One_Train_Input, Team_Two_Train_Input, Team_One_Stats_Train_Input, Team_Two_Stats_Train_Input],
         y=Train_Output, 
          validation_data=([Date_Input_Validate, Team_One_Input_Validate, Team_Two_Input_Validate, Team_One_Stats_Input_Validate, Team_Two_Stats_Input_Validate], Output_Validate),
         epochs=200)
```

Comment: There are multiple issues that could cause this error. Please post your code

Comment: Please post the code of your model.

Comment: @DapperDuck , the post has been edited to include the code. If you have any questions please let me know how I can help.

Comment: It seems you may be passing string data as input to the training process.

Comment: @TFer2 When reading through the Tensorflow Documentation, It allows states Tensors can be of String Value, does that not apply when using them as inputs for a model?